# How to check if a bookmark contains a table?

Tags: java, openoffice-writer, uno

Is it possible to determine when a [`Bookmark`](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/Bookmark.html) contains a [`TextTable`](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/TextTable.html)? I thought about looking through [`XTextRange`](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/XTextRange.html) objects, however, the documentation does not specify anything about comparing ranges.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you asking whether the bookmark is located *within* a TextTable?  That would be easy to determine.  I assume in my answer below that you do mean *contains*, as the question states, and that the bookmark is across a range of text rather than just a single location.

Comment: No, I'm asking about a **table** within a **bookmark**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So starting with the following code:

```
XBookmarksSupplier xBookmarksSupplier =
    (XBookmarksSupplier)UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
    XBookmarksSupplier.class, xComponent);
    XNameAccess xNamedBookmarks = xBookmarksSupplier.getBookmarks();
Object bookmark = xNamedBookmarks.getByName("TextAndTable");
XTextContent xBookmarkContent = (XTextContent)UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
    XTextContent.class, bookmark);
XTextRange xTextRange = xBookmarkContent.getAnchor();
```

It sounds like you are asking how to determine if there are one or more text tables that are located within the range specified by `xTextRange`.

To do this, I normally use the [View Cursor](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Writer/API/View_cursor).  It's slow, but a normal text cursor is not able to traverse different text objects, so it would fail if there are text tables or other objects within the range.

Here is my Python class, which perhaps you can adapt to Java:

```
def differentPlaces(oCurs1, oCurs2):
    """Test using compareRegion to see if two cursors are in different places.
    If compareRegion fails, such as after a nested table, return False.
    """
    try:
        oText = oCurs1.getText()
        return oText.compareRegionEnds(oCurs1, oCurs2) != 0
    except IllegalArgumentException:
        logger.info("Could not compare region.")
        return False

class RangeCompare:
    """Compare the viewcursor to a text range (a location).
    Can be useful when traversing a cursor over a range.
    The range is expected not to be modified.
    """
    def __init__(self, rangeEnd, viewCursor):
        self.oVC = viewCursor
        self.rangeEnd = rangeEnd
        self.endX = -1
        self.endY = -1

    def getCoords(self):
        if self.endY > -1:
            return
        # remember where we were, because we'll need to use the viewcursor
        originalVC = self.oVC.getText().createTextCursorByRange(self.oVC)

        self.oVC.gotoRange(self.rangeEnd, False)
        self.endX = self.oVC.getPosition().X
        self.endY = self.oVC.getPosition().Y

        self.oVC.gotoRange(originalVC, False)

    def compareVC(self):
        """Compare the viewcursor to the range.
        Assume we are travelling with the viewcursor.
        See if it is up to the end yet or not.
        The comparison is done by checking the physical position of the cursor.
        Returns -1 if the VC location is less than self.rangeEnd, 0 if it is
        the same, and 1 if it is greater.
        Returns -2 if they are on the same line but not in the same spot, and
        it's not certain which location is greater.
        """
        self.getCoords()
        curX = self.oVC.getPosition().X
        curY = self.oVC.getPosition().Y
        if curY < self.endY:
            logger.debug("%d < %d", curY, self.endY)
            return -1
        elif curY > self.endY:
            logger.debug("%d > %d", curY, self.endY)
            return 1
        elif curY == self.endY:
            if curX == self.endX:
                if differentPlaces(self.oVC, self.rangeEnd):
                    # There is probably a word-final diacritic that doesn't
                    # change the position, so we're not to the end yet.
                    logger.debug("Including word-final diacritic.")
                    return -2
                # We're at the end.
                logger.debug(
                    "VC same loc as text range (%d, %d).", curX, curY)
                return 0
            else:
                logger.debug("Probably haven't gone far enough.")
                return -2
```

Instantiate the class with something like `rangeCompare = RangeCompare(xTextRange.getEnd(), xViewCursor)`.

Move the view cursor to the start of `xTextRange`.  Then keep calling `xViewCursor.goRight(1, False)` in a loop.  Each time, check if the cursor is located in a TextTable.  Stop when `rangeCompare.compareVC() > 0`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll check it as soon as I can